# Google Streetview blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cors, cors-anywhere

Im want to integrate StreetView from google maps into an webapplication but Im getting blocked by CORS. Im basically pulling the streetview as an background into my Three.js webbapplication. The URL works standalone but in my application I get cors errors. Any way of fixing this?

Here is my URL:
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=40.7580336,-73.9855832&cbp=11,0,0,0,0

I have also tried with using cors-anywhere before as below:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=40.7580336,-73.9855832&cbp=11,0,0,0,0

but with no success.

My code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // BG
        var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, controls, bgTexture, bgWidth, bgHeight;
        loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

        var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=40.7580336,-73.9855832&cbp=11,0,0,0,0";

        bgTexture = loader.load(url,

            function (texture) {
                var img = texture.image;
                bgWidth = img.width;
                bgHeight = img.height;
                resize();
            }
        );
        scene.background = bgTexture;
        //

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        animate();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could be an api key issue. Are you registered with google on api key?

Comment: oh, just noticed. I cannot access this for free right? :/ In that case that could be the problem ...

Comment: It's free for so many thousands of hits in a day. If that's the problem. May not be the issue at all.

Comment: I read here under static street view: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/?_ga=2.217374166.1714179850.1598291238-1610688279.1598291238

Comment: Sign up for an api key. Dont do the payment part. You have options as developer. You'll get an inverted (xor graphics) of the street view since its not paid for, even for free hits.

Comment: @GetSet You can't sign up for a key without providing a credit card (there are credits, so the credit card may not be charged, but you can't not "do the payment part".

Comment: @acroscene are you using the static street view API?  Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: yes I basically just need to grab an image from the streetview. I dont need any of the interactivity

Comment: Since when @geocodezip? Got a number of test apps for cli where I personally haven't give any of such payment details. Sure there comes some unsavory watermarks and other unsavory visual artifacts. But I wouldnt say not possible. ..... Possibly i am using a legacy api key before the paywall, likely

Comment: I added my API key to the test url below but when I pasted it in the browser I actually got: "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project" https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=41.403609,2.174448&size=456x456&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: Yes, because as what geocodezip mentioned, your project is required to be associated with a valid billing account to prevent any limit errors or a degraded experience. For a more detailed information on how you can create a billing account, please visit this link: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#create_a_new_billing_account

If you would also require a personalized communication channel, I would suggest that you [create a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case) in the Cloud Developer Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't embed the Google Maps application directly into your application. You'll have to use their [Street View Service API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) or, if you only need a static image without any interaction, their [Street View Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview)
.

The documentation explains in detail how you can achieve that.